# Angles and relations of in triangles and quadilaterals

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

**Hello,**
There was a question in geometry which was marked as a simple question as follows(Diagram below):-

> The diagonal AC of a quadrilateral $CDAB$ bisects the $\angle DCB$. It is given that $BC=BD$. $\angle CAB = 80$, $\angle DBC = 20$, then the measure of $\angle ADC$ in degree is......

Lets take the point of intersection of the two diagonals as O. Now since $\triangle DCB$ is isosceles, $\angle D$ (Of the triangle) + $\angle C + 20 = 180$. Simplifying, we get $\angle CDA = 80$, and thus $\angle ACD$ and $\angle ACB = 40.$ Now solving for $   \triangle ACB$ (Taking the whole of $\angle C$ as $20+x$) we get $x = 40$. Now $\angle O$ in  $\triangle AOC = 120$ and using vertically opposite angles formula, i got the value of $\angle AOB$ and $DOC = 60$. Now i'm stuck here. From my diagram i can see that $\angle CAB$ and $\angle BDC$ are equal to each other And $\angle ABD$ and $\angle DCA$ are equal to each other. I thought of assuming $\angle BDA = \angle  ACB$ but i have no formal proof for that.

**ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $\angle CDB=\angle CAB$, quadrilateral $ABCD$ is cyclic. It follows that $\angle ADB=\angle ACB=40°$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But can you please give me a proof why the quadilateral is cyclic?

Comment: Because if two equal angles insist on the same chord, then they belong to the same circular arc.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't get you. Can you please elaborate or at least send me a link to the explanation

Comment: See here for the inverse of the corollary of the inscribed angle theorem: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/Munching/inscribed.shtml